Section Array in Sanity IO and NextJS not detecting _type
I've been trying for a few days now to get my component array to pull through to the page template but I can't get it working.
Here is my page.tsx (where I think the problem lies)
import { getPage } from "@/sanity/sanity-utils";
import { PortableText } from "@portabletext/react";
import TextSectionComponent from "@/sanity/components/text-section-component";
import ImageSectionComponent from "@/sanity/components/image-section-component";
import type { Metadata } from "next";

type Props = {
  params: { 
    slug: string;
  }
}

// Dynamic metadata generation
export const generateMetadata = async ({ params }: Props): Promise<Metadata> => {
  const page = await getPage(params.slug);
  return {
    title: { 
      absolute: `${page.title} | Website.com`,
      template: ` | Website.com`,
    },
  };
}

export default async function Page({ params }: Props) {
  const page = await getPage(params.slug);
  console.log('Fetched Page:', page); // Log the fetched page object
  
  // Log fetched page data for debugging
  console.log("Fetched page:", page);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="">{page.title}</h1>
      <div className="text-lg text-gray-700 mt-10">
        {/* Ensure PortableText handles array of blocks */}
        <PortableText value={page.content} />
      </div>
      <div className="sections">
        {/* Map over sections and render based on _type */}
        {page.sections?.map((section, index) => {
          // Log each section for debugging
          console.log("Rendering section:", section);

          // Ensure section and _type are defined
          if (section && section._type) {
            switch (section._type) {
              case 'textSection':
                return (
                  <TextSectionComponent 
                    key={section._key} 
                    title={section.title ?? "Untitled"} 
                    content={section.content ?? "No content available"} 
                  />
                );
              case 'imageSection':
                return (
                  <ImageSectionComponent 
                    key={section._key} 
                    title={section.title ?? "Untitled"} 
                    content={section.content ?? "No content available"} 
                  />
                );
              // Add more case statements for other section types if needed
              default:
                return null;
            }
          } else {
            return null; // Handle null or undefined sections
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Here are the logs I get
Fetched page: {
  sections: [ null ],
  subpages: null,
  _id: 'd6523118-3b84-42cc-920b-1a6b1180ffef',
  _createdAt: '2024-06-22T10:05:20Z',
  title: 'About',
  slug: 'About',
  content: [
    {
      style: 'normal',
      _key: '2fd5222718b0',
      markDefs: [],
      children: [Array],
      _type: 'block'
    }
  ],
  navLevel: 'about'
}

I have no other errors.
This is how Page Schema looks
// sanity/schema/page-schema.ts
import textSection from './objects/text-section-schema'; // Adjust the import path as needed
import imageSection from './objects/image-section-schema';

const page = {
  name: "page",
  title: "Pages",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "title",
      title: "Title",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      name: "slug",
      title: "Slug",
      type: "slug",
      options: { source: "title", maxLength: 96 }
    },
    {
      name: "navLevel",
      title: "Navigation Level",
      type: "string",
      initialValue: 'Primary',
      options: {
        list: [
          { title: 'about', value: 'about' },
          // Add more options as needed
        ],
      }
    },
    {
      name: "content",
      title: "Content",
      type: "array",
      of: [
        { type: "block" }
        // Define other block types if needed
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'sections',
      title: 'Sections',
      type: 'array',
      of: [
        { type: 'textSection', title: 'Text Section' },
        { type: 'imageSection', title: 'Image Section' }
        // Add more types as needed
      ]
    }
  ]
};

export default page;


the component:
// components/text-section-component.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { PortableText } from "@portabletext/react";

type TextSectionProps = {
  title: any;
  content: any; // Assuming content is structured portable text
};

const TextSectionComponent: React.FC<TextSectionProps> = ({ title, content }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2><PortableText value={title} /></h2>
      <PortableText value={content} />
      {/* Additional rendering logic as needed */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextSectionComponent;


and Index.ts
import article from './article-schema'
import page from "./page-schema"
import textSection from "./objects/text-section-schema"
import imageSection from "./objects/image-section-schema"

const schemas = [article, page, textSection, imageSection];

export default schemas;


Even though in the admin for the about page I have selected the Text Section in the array, added content, and saved it, when I load the about page in browser locally, I see  and nothing in it.
I'm expecting to load the About page and see "Section Title" and "Section Content" (the text I entered in Sanity admin for the added section).
All I see is the page title and page content but nothing for the sections added & published.
I've tried using AI to help but it goes in circles and never solves the problem.
I feel like the issue is related to _type, I think that when rendering the page elements it can't find the section types assigned to the page, and so returns null (I could be completely wrong) but feels like it is along those lines.
